# How to change username in LinkedIn Outlook Connector

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, outlook-addin, linkedin

I'm running the lastest version of the LinkedIn Connector for Outlook which you can download here:

http://www.linkedin.com/static?key=microsoft_outlook

I recently changed my username on LinkedIn since one of my old email addresses was retired. However, I can't seem to change the username that comes up to authenticate to LinkedIn inside Outlook.

I've already tried:

- Uninstall/Reinstall of the connector
- Searching the registry for my old email and changing it to my new email

Anyone know how this can be done?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a web site.  This question belongs on webapps.stackexchange.com.  (BTW, what happened to the message about not migrating old questions?)

Comment: @Scott the question asks how to use an add-on for Microsoft Outlook that connects to LinkedIn. It's not about using LinkedIn in a browser, so it's not appropriate for migration.

Comment: @nhinkle: OK, I guess I read it too quickly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do this:

1. Click on the green "plus" icon in the "People pane" in Outlook (down under the email, where all social network activity is visible).
2. Select "On Another Social Network" there.
3. You'll see a list of all connected social network accounts. Delete LinkedIn account, since you cannot change the username.
4. Add new LinkedIn account with the correct username/password.

Comment: The answer worked, with one caveat. With my system (OL 2010), when I deleted the LinkedIn account, the connector stayed there and all I had to do was reenter the new information. I think this corresponds with step 4 above, but it wasn't clear that you DO NOT have to reinstall the connector after you've "deleted" the LinkedIn account.